# Double sum subtraction with one missing term

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, physics, factorial, substitution

If I have some sum and subtract another why is the following relation true?

$$\sum_{h}^{n}  \sum_{i}^{n} f(h,i) - \sum_{h \neq \theta}^{n}  \sum_{i \neq \theta}^{n} f(h,i) =  \sum_{i}^{n} f(\theta,i) $$

Comment: Your notation is not very clear, which I think may be contributing to the confusion. What is meant by $\sum_h^n$? Does this mean $\sum_{h=1}^n$? What is mean by $\sum_{h \neq \theta}^n$?

Comment: Sorry. The first question yes. And the second means summing over everything but 1 term which we call $\theta $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}, \theta \in [n]$ and $N_\theta = [n] \setminus \{\theta\}$.

I am assuming

- $\sum_h^n$ is really $\sum_{h=1}^n$ and
- $\sum_{h \ne \theta}^n$ is really $\sum_{h \in N_\theta}$

Then,

- the first sum on the left includes all indices $(h,i)$ where $h,i \in [n]$
- the second sum on the left includes all indices $(h,i)$ where $h,i \in N_\theta$

The difference includes all terms where $h=\theta$ or $i = \theta$, i.e.
$$
\sum_{h\ne \theta} f(h, \theta) + \sum_{i\ne \theta} f(\theta, i) + f(\theta,\theta)
= \sum_{h\ne \theta} f(h, \theta) + \sum_i^n f(\theta, i)
$$

---

A slightly modified version of your expression would be true:
$$\sum_{h}^{n}  \sum_{i}^{n} f(h,i) - \sum_{h \neq \theta}^{n}  \sum_{i}^n f(h,i) =  \sum_{i}^{n} f(\theta,i) $$